# Problem: Routing from a sibling component to another with id param causing and component template warining object to be undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Could someone help?

The component `HealthCandidatesComponent` contains a list with all candidates in a reactive table (MatTable). By clicking a candidate in a row, it routes to a sibling component, `HealthCandidateComponent`, for the single candidate (**please note** '...Candidate...' without '*s*'), passing its id to be retrieved from the backend. The problem is that when I retrieve the candidate by id from the service class, the string interpolations in the receiving component's template state that the candidate object is undefined, even though it displays its value.

[image]

Although it works I don't want the candidate retrieved to be undefined, because I want to use it as param to an Array, like GENDERS[candidate?.gender?.description], but when I try to do that, it throws an error:

[image]

Only because the candidate is undefined.

How can I retrieve the candidate entity via routing between sibling components without it becoming undefined?

`HealthCandidatesComponent.html` (Sender sibling 1) - MatTable:

```
(...)
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="onCandidateClick(row.id)"></tr>
```

`HealthCandidatesComponent.ts` (routing function):

```
(...)
onCandidateClick(candidateId: string) {
    this.router.navigate([`/admin/mitarbeiter/kandidaten/${candidateId}`]);
}
```

`HealthCandidateComponent.ts` (Receiver sibling 2):

```
candidate!: ServiceWorkerAdminDto;
(...)

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    const candidateId: string = params['id'];
    this.onGetCandidate(candidateId);
  });
}

onGetCandidate(candidateId: string) {
  this.candidateService.getServiceWorker(candidateId).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.candidate = data;
    }
  );
}
```

`ServiceWorkerAdminDto.ts` class:

```
export class ServiceWorkerAdminDto {
  id!: string;
  gender!: Gender;
  firstName!: string;
  lastName!: string;
  birthdate!: string;
  religion!: Religion;
  pensionType!: PensionType;
  workStatus!: WorkStatus;
  sector!: Sector;
  nationality!: Country;
  identity!: Identity;
  civilState!: CivilState;
  appliedOn!: string;
  applicationType!: ApplicationType;
  work!: Work;
  kids!: Kid[];
}
```

`candidate.service.ts`:

```
getServiceWorker(workerId: string): Observable<ServiceWorkerAdminDto> {
  const swUrl = `${this.apiUrl}/workerController/getWorkerById?workerId=${workerId}`;
  return this.http.get<ServiceWorkerAdminDto>(swUrl);
}
```

Comment: It’s a typing issue. Candidate can never be undefined according to the way you typed it. So add | undefined to it. Your bigger issue is actually having nested subscriptions - which will probably cause you other issues in the future.

Comment: What is your `ServiceWorkerAdminDto` look like?

Comment: @paranaaan I upadted with the ServiceWorkerAdminDto class.

Comment: I am using Lazy Loading in the routing module. Does that influence?